# Set object attribute based on zipped attribute, value pairs

Tags: python

How would you simplify `calculate_commission()` if the commission percentages for each attribute was defined by the zipped list and the length of the zipped list could potentially increase (ex. `...('price_201', 2.3),`) ?

```
zipped_price_and_commission = [
    ('price_4', .04),
    ('price_3', .034),
    ('price_2', .029),
    ('price_1', .021),
]

class Price:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.price = kwargs.get('price')
        self.price_1 = 2
        self.price_2 = 2.5
        self.price_3 = 3
        self.price_4 = 5

    def calculate_commission(self):
        if self.price >= self.price_4:
            commission = .04
        elif self.price >= self.price_3:
            commission = .034
        elif self.price >= self.price_2:
            commission = .029
        elif self.price >= self.price_1:
            commission = .021
        else:
            commission = 0

        setattr(self, 'commission', commission)

 IN: price = Price(price=3.3)
 IN: price.calculate_commission()
 IN: print(price.commission)
OUT: 0.034
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first place, you should define all attributes in the **init** function. For example, you would get an error if someone tried to access the commission attribute without checking it first. So, just to be sure, you should initialize it with something.

Assuming that there is no need to have the commission as a zipped list, you can just do it like this:

```
comission = [ 0.04, 0.034, 0.029, 0.021]
class Price:
    def __init__(self, cost):
        self.price = cost 

        self.prices = [5,3,2.5,2]
        self.commission = 0 
    def calculate_commission(self):

        for index, prc in enumerate(self.prices):
            if self.price >= prc:
                self.commission = comission[index]
                break 
price = Price()
price.calculate_commission()
print(price.commission)
```

However, if you do need a zipped list, you can change the self.comission line to

```
      self.commission = zipped_price_and_commission[index][1]
```

Edit: after seeing your update: If the number of commissions increases, you just have to update the self.prices variable to reflect them. You should also pass the prices as an argument to the class, instead of setting it inside the class

Comment: I'd still use `zip` in the loop: `for p, c in zip(prices, commissions): ...` Looks more "pythonic" than `enumerate`

Answer (score 2):

You can use a dictionary:

```py
commissions = {
    'price_4': .04,
    'price_3': .034,
    'price_2': .029,
    'price_1': .021}
```

Then, in `calculate_commission()`:

```py
    def calculate_commission(self):
        if self.price >= self.price_4:
            commission = commissions['price_4']
        elif self.price >= self.price_3:
            commission = commissions['price_3']
        elif self.price >= self.price_2:
            commission = commissions['price_2']
        elif self.price >= self.price_1:
            commission = commissions['price_1']
        else:
            commission = 0

        setattr(self, 'commission', commission)
```

Comment: I added some more details to the OP. Then length of the zipped list could potentially increase. For example the price levels may go up to `'price_200'`

Answer (score 0):

```
zipped_price_and_commission = [
('price_4', .04),
('price_3', .034),
('price_2', .029),
('price_1', .021),
```

]

```
class Price:

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.price = kwargs.get('price')
        self.price_1 = 2
        self.price_2 = 2.5
        self.price_3 = 3
        self.price_4 = 5
        self.priceData = { 'price_4': 5,'price_3': 3,'price_2': 2.5,'price_1': 2}

    def calculate_commission(self):
        commission = 0
        for price , commision in zipped_price_and_commission:
            if self.price >= self.priceData[price]:
                commission = commision
                break
        setattr(self, 'commission', commission)

price = Price(price=3.3)

price.calculate_commission()

print(price.commission)
```